# Service started again after killed by task manager

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I've various options to sync data between android app and server. I'm using `AlarmManager` to trigger sync with user choices. I've one which says `Never Update (Update Manually)` in which i cancel  with `toStopServiceAlarm()` the `AlarmManager`.

#### Que:

*It's working fine as long as my application won't be killed by any task manager. As soon as it's killed by Task Manager application service again started with `Never Update(Update Manually)` where i already cancelled any `AlarmManager`* trigger.

*Can anybody help me in preserving my application behaviour even if it's killed by Task Manager? Sync get called as per user choice only.*

Code Snippet:-

```
public class ServiceAlarm extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
Intent service = new Intent(context, UploadData.class); //UploadData is my service
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}

public void startServiceAlarm(String times)
{
 context = SmartConsultant.getApplication().getApplicationContext();
 alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);      
 Intent intent = new Intent(SmartConsultant.getApplication().getApplicationContext(), UploadData.class);
 alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

 switch(Integer.parseInt(times))
 {
  case 0://midnight
            alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
  break;
  ... cases for different interval of sync
 }
}

public void toStopServiceAlarm(String times)
{
   if (alarmMgr != null) {
  alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your problem lies in your service, most likely. Restarting a service is what will occur if your `onStartCommand()` returns something like `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, and that's the default behavior of `IntentService`. You can call `setIntentRedelivery(false)` in `onCreate()` of your `IntentService` to disable this.

Comment: @CommonsWare My Service `extends Service`.I'm not overriding `onStartCommand`in Service. So should i include `setIntentRedelivery(false)` in onCreate()?

Comment: "So should i include setIntentRedelivery(false) in onCreate()?" -- if you change your service to extend `IntentService`, yes. Otherwise, return `START_NOT_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`. Also, make sure that you are stopping your service at some point and that you are releasing the `WakeLock` at the same time.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks! Work as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per CommonsWare, I just need to override `onStartCommand()` with `START_NOT_STICKY` which will make my service loosly tight with Android and won't start once it's killed by `TaskManager`. That's what behaviour expected from that running `Service`.

Code Snippet:

```
public class UploadData extends Service
{
...
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```